# Converting a sbyte to char cls-compliantly

Tags: c#

I have C# wrapper of a C Library. It has a method that returns an sbyte that is supposed to represent a char.  I can use Convert.ToChar but this is not CLS-compliant. What is the best practice for converting this sbyte to a char compliantly?

Comment: Is the 'char' a native or managed type? Also, what is the purpose of the conversion - is it just a value or do you care that it is validly converted to the correct character for use in a string?

Answer (score 3):

System.Buffer.BlockCopy can be used to convert sbyte arrays to byte arrays. Then, you can use the System.Text.ASCIIEncoding to do the conversion of the byte array to ASCII text.

Answer (score 2):

Now that you changed the question :) Sbyte is not cls compliant to begin with. Make the wrapper use byte.